# Github pages react wrong routing

Tags: reactjs, github-pages, vite

I have deployed a react js website to github pages here https://marknjoroge.github.io/Elizabeth-Law-Firm/. The site is just blank and the console shows the following error:

```
GET https://marknjoroge.github.io/assets/index-ecb5047a.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

From the error, I can see that it is trying to get my assets from my `https://marknjoroge.github.io/` instead of `https://marknjoroge.github.io/Elizabeth-Law-Firm`.

Here is my code

`package.json`

```
{
  "homepage": "https://marknjoroge.github.io/Elizabeth-Law-Firm",
  "name": "elizabeth-firm",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d dist"
  },
```

`main.js`

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <HashRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                <Route path="/contact" element={ <Contact/> } />
                <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
                <Route path="/practices" element={<PracticeAreas />} />
            </Routes>
        </HashRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>
)
```

Please help.

Comment: "deploy": "gh-pages -d build", <- this is what docs say

Comment: `build`, or in my case, `dist`, is the folder that the build files have been stored.

Answer (score 0):

found the solution on Vite's website https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy.html#github-pages

> Set the correct base in vite.config.js ... If you are deploying to https://USERNAME.github.io/REPO/, then set base to '/REPO/'

`vite.config.js`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  base: '/Elizabeth-Law-Firm/',
})
```